# recovering database from mysql/data

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, recovery

ive got 2 versions of xampp, the one is old and the other new.
i have only been able to back up the whole old xampp folder.
the old xampp folder has a password set on the root user while the new xampp version does not have any password.

i have tried copying the mysql/data to the new mysql/data but ive got problems.
i have recovered the databases but not their table contents.

the status on the table collation is set to 'in use'.
and there is an error message that tells you that the 'table does not exist in the engine.'

how can i recover my database.
or could i use the old copy of xampp to work in my new laptop?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you did exactly and/or what database(s) you want to recover. Have you e.g. lost your old password and try to put old databases into the new passwordless server to reset the password? Do you have relevant data in both installations, and want to combine them? Generally: to reuse the `/data` folder, you will need to delete/move the existing data folder content and move/copy the new one *completely and including all subfolders*. Mixing old and new files/missing subfolders/..., may result in problems like you are describing. If you did that, mention it/your goals.